# Как реализовать сортировку в doctrine?

Tags: sql, doctrine

Всем привет. Есть запрос sql
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af6428

```
SELECT * FROM `category`
  ORDER BY COALESCE(`orderNum`, `name`)
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM `category`
  ORDER BY `orderNum` IS NULL, `name`;
```

сам код

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $qb->join('s.category', 'c');
    $qb->where('c.code = :categoryCode')
        ->setParameter('categoryCode', self::MOBILE);
    $qb->andWhere('s.id <> c.primaryService');

    $qb->andWhere('s.isActive = true');
    $qb->andWhere('s.isVisible = true');

    $qb->orderBy('s.name', 'asc');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

как сделать их через doctrine orm?

Comment: добавьте код, который у вас есть сейчас

Comment: Добавил код на запроса

Comment: `coalesce` можете в селект добавить и сортировать по алиасу

Comment: можно подробнее?